# Gradle Project on Eclipse does not show the src/main/java and src/main/test

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am learning gradle for my tasks at organisation, and was trying to create a new gradle project. However, I am not able to see any src/main/java folder structure.
It looks like below :
[image: Folder Structure]

I tried manually adding folders, and creating a class. But I do not get that option as well : [image: No class option]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1234#issuecomment-1554473896